# Django channels work on local but not on server, Error during WebSocket handshake

Tags: django, nginx, socket.io, django-channels

Website is loading fine but the channels are not working. In console I get:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://fortests.ovh/8' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Server: Ubuntu 16.04 on Digital Ocean
nginx version: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
Redis server v=3.2.8

my settings.py:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [('localhost', 6379)],
        },
        'ROUTING': 'slist.routing.channel_routing',
    }
}
```

wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "slist.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

consumers.py

```
import json
from channels import Group
from channels.auth import channel_session_user_from_http, channel_session_user

from .models import Item

# Connected to websocket.connect
@channel_session_user_from_http
def ws_add(message):
    # Accept the connection
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})
    # Add to the users group
    Group("users").add(message.reply_channel)
```

routing.py

```
from channels.routing import route
from tobuy.consumers import ws_add, ws_receive, ws_disconnect

channel_routing = [
    route("websocket.connect", ws_add),
    route("websocket.receive", ws_receive),
    route("websocket.disconnect", ws_disconnect),
]
```

js

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/' + {{ active_list.id }});
```

nginx settings

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_name fortests.ovh;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    root /home/kuba1/slistproject/slistvenv/src;
}

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/kuba1/slistproject/slistvenv/src/slist.sock;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

}
}
```

Comment: I suppose that `slisock` is `sli.sock` in your server otherwise your socket couldn't be found.

Comment: you're right the proxy_pass is slist.sock not slisock on the server

Answer (score 1):

I also had above 404 error when using daphne (channels 2) in a docker setting. In ended up with below nginx conf:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

upstream websocket {
        server daphne:8000;
}


server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name  localhost;


  root   /var/www;
  location /static {
      index  index.html index.htm;
  }

  location / {
      root /var/www;
      try_files $uri $uri/index.html @daphne;

      expires max;
      access_log off;
  }

  location @daphne {
    proxy_pass http://websocket;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

  }
```

where daphne (on line 5) was the name of the container running the daphne process.